# Trying to create a filtered logical replication on postgresql but the whole table gets replicated

Tags: postgresql, logical-replication

I am trying to create a logical replication with filter between two postgresql 16 servers

**On publisher:**

```
create table repl_sample
(   id int not null, 
    name varchar (64) not null, 
    age int not null, 
 constraint pk_repl_sample primary key (id)
)

alter table repl_sample replica identity default 

create publication repl_sample_publication
for table repl_sample 
where (id < 7)
```

(I've also tried with replica identity full)

**On subscriber:**

```
create table repl_sample
(   id int not null, 
name varchar (64) not null, 
age int not null, 
 constraint pk_repl_sample primary key (id)
)

alter table repl_sample replica identity default

create subscription repl_sample_subscription
connection 'host=192.168.4.1 port=5432 user=postgres dbname=sampledb'
publication repl_sample_publication
```

And after that, all of the rows are replicated on the subscription table regardless of filter, which is not what I wanted, *I wanted only rows where id < 7*

---

Edit:
Answers to Adrian's questions.

1. Yes, I am sure the subscription is pointing to the correct publication database because I've created these two sample databases with only one table to try out the logical replication.
2. I have just inserted 20 sample rows on the publication side
3. This is the log on the publication side:

   2024-03-05 12:44:36.114 CET [1602854] STATEMENT: CREATE_REPLICATION_SLOT "pg_80016_sync_80009_7184072373314447002" LOGICAL pgoutput USE_SNAPSHOT

   2024-03-05 12:44:36.248 CET [1602854] LOG:  starting logical decoding for slot "pg_80016_sync_80009_7184072373314447002"

   2024-03-05 12:44:36.248 CET [1602854] DETAIL:  Streaming transactions committing after 9A/F98C8370, reading WAL from 9A/F98C8338.

   2024-03-05 12:44:36.248 CET [1602854] STATEMENT:  START_REPLICATION SLOT "pg_80016_sync_80009_7184072373314447002" LOGICAL 9A/F98C8370 (proto_version '2', publication_names '"repl_sample_publication"')

   2024-03-05 12:44:36.248 CET [1602854] LOG:  logical decoding found consistent point at 9A/F98C8338

   2024-03-05 12:44:36.248 CET [1602854] DETAIL:  There are no running transactions.

   2024-03-05 12:44:36.248 CET [1602854] STATEMENT:  START_REPLICATION SLOT "pg_80016_sync_80009_7184072373314447002" LOGICAL 9A/F98C8370 (proto_version '2', publication_names '"repl_sample_publication"')

   2024-03-05 12:48:25.289 CET [698] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
   2024-03-05 12:48:29.842 CET [698] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 46 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=4.537 s, sync=0.007 s, total=
   4.553 s; sync files=31, longest=0.002 s, average=0.001 s; distance=277 kB, estimate=3808 kB; lsn=9A/F98EC808, redo lsn=9A/F98EAC30

Comment: Add to your question text, as text, answers to the following: 1) Are you sure the subscription is pointing at the correct publication database?  2) What operations are being done on the table on the publication side? 3) What does the  log Postgres show is actually hitting the database on the publication side?

Comment: Ok, I think I know now what seems to be the problem.

If the table is populated before the publication and subscription are created (as was in my case) then the 'where' clause seems to be irrelevant, all of the rows from the published table are replicated. It only affects the data inserted after the creation of the publication. Now, I am not sure if that might be a bug (I don't think nobody has noticed this before) but I presume it should be emphasized somewhere in the documentation (or at least I haven't found it anywhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is to be expected during the initial coping of the data. Perhaps you missed this [warning from the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication-row-filter.html#LOGICAL-REPLICATION-ROW-FILTER-INITIAL-DATA-SYNC):

> Because initial data synchronization does not take into account the [publish](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createpublication.html#SQL-CREATEPUBLICATION-WITH-PUBLISH) parameter when copying existing table data, some rows may be copied that would not be replicated using DML. Refer to [Section 31.7.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication-architecture.html#LOGICAL-REPLICATION-SNAPSHOT), and see [Section 31.2.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication-subscription.html#LOGICAL-REPLICATION-SUBSCRIPTION-EXAMPLES) for examples.

(It is an omission that the documentation does not mention the `WHERE` clause.)

You can either skip the initial data copy when you create the subscription and transfer the existing data in some other way, or you can delete the unwanted rows on the subscriber.

Comment: Yes, I have finally found out by experimenting and spending some 2 days trying to figure out what was happening. I have not noticed that part of the documentation.

Comment: That's the problem with comprehensive documentation: it becomes harder to find the needle in the haystack.